# является ли функция SUBSTRING(); "чистым" sql-92

Tags: mysql

При написании запроса мне нужно пользоваться исключительно стандартом sql-92. Является ли `SUBSTRING();` "чистым" sql-92? И есть ли какой то подробный справочник того, что в нём поддерживается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, `SUBSTRING` входит в SQL-92 ([см. стандарт](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt), п. 4.2.2.1):

```
     <character substring function> is a triadic function, SUBSTRING,
     that returns a string extracted from a given string according
     to a given numeric starting position and a given numeric length.
     Truncation occurs when the implied starting and ending positions
     are not both within the given string.
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот ссылка на текст стандарта SQL-92:

[Файл sql1992.txt](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt)

Пользоваться, конечно, не очень удобно, но с помощью контектного поиска можно определить, описана ли та или иная конструкция конкретного диалекта SQL в этом стандарте.

Например, SUBSTRING находится в списке зарезервированных слов на странице с индексом ***X3H2-92-154/DBL CBR-002*** и далее при описании строковых функций на странице с индексом ***X3H2-92-154/DBL CBR-002***